# Credit card payment gateway with "Transparent Redirect" in Europe

Tags: php, credit-card

I'm looking for credit card payment gateway similar to [Braintree’s Transparent Redirect](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/services/pci-compliance)  but working in Europe area. Does anyone know such a gateway?

Edit: Sorry for tagging it with "php" but since I will implement it in php I think it makes sens.

Comment: I'm curious how this worked out for you. Did paygate.de really do the job? Hope you are willing to share your experiences. Would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.paygate.de does support this.

Answer (score 1):

Braintree is planning to arrive in Europe. You can add yourself to the wait list here: https://braintreepayments.com/tour/international